# Error in function from project euler when using largest signed int value

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I was doing euler problems for fun and decided to see how fast my computer would solve this problem for the biggest signed int: https://projecteuler.net/problem=1

Unfortunately I get a negative value (overflow?) when I try using the largest signed int value, 2147483647, as you can see in this picture:

[image]

Why do I get a seemingly correct answer when using `2147483647-1` but get a wrong value when using `2147483647`?

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getsums(int v) {
    int sum, i; sum = i = 0;
    for(;i<v; i++){
        if ( i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0 ){
            sum +=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    int upperlimit = 0;
    int sums = 0;

    printf("Intervalo de 0 a (escreva um numero)\n");
    printf(">>");

    scanf("%d", &upperlimit);
    sums = getsums(upperlimit);

    printf("somas dos multiplos de 3 e 5 no intervalo [0;%d] e: %d\n", upperlimit, sums);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: when asking a runtime question, post code that cleanly compiles.  The posted code is missing the `#include` statements (which I do not want to try to read your mind as to which header files the actual code uses.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` or better, both.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @user3629249 I decided to avoid cluttering the code for a simple question like this, since this is a really basic euler project exercise. I thought it was obvious enough that I was using #include <stdio.h> Edited the question.

Comment: posting the `#include` statements is never 'cluttering the code`  Cluttering the code would be using a multiplier of `sizeof(char)` or casting the returned value from a call to `malloc()` and similar such 'useless' expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main problem is that a `int` is not large enough to hold the `sum`.

Suggest the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t getsums(size_t v)
{
    size_t sum = 0;

    for(size_t i=0; i<v; i++)
    {
        if ( i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0 )
        {
            sum +=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}


int main(void)
{
    size_t upperlimit = 0;
    size_t sums = 0;

    printf("Intervalo de 0 a (escreva um numero)\n");
    printf(">>");

    scanf("%lu", &upperlimit);
    sums = getsums(upperlimit);

    printf("somas dos multiplos de 3 e 5 no intervalo [0;%lu] e: %lu\n", upperlimit, sums);

    return 0;
}
```

which yields the following:

```
Intervalo de 0 a (escreva um numero)
>>2147483647
somas dos multiplos de 3 e 5 no intervalo [0;2147483647] e: 1076060070465310994
```

and the following:

```
Intervalo de 0 a (escreva um numero)
>>2147483646
somas dos multiplos de 3 e 5 no intervalo [0;2147483646] e: 1076060068317827348
```

Comment: Decided to accept this answer instead because it provides more information and taught me about t_size. I have a question: is there a limit for t_size?

Comment: `size_t`, not `t_size`  is a short cut for `unsigned long`  So since `unsigned long` is not defined for the actual length characteristic in the C standard, other than 'at least as long as a `unsigned int` it depends somewhat on your compiler implementation.  On my comiler `gcc`, it is 64 bits.  So is defined the same as `uint64_t`

Answer (score 3):

`int` and `unsigned` are not enough to store the result for that high input. That positive number you got in the other case is also incorrect. To see, consider `INT_MAX - 3` (this or the three numbers above it must be divisible by `3`). If you add the first two numbers from `INT_MAX - 3` down to `0`, it means you overflow `INT_MAX` definitely already, because the second number is definitely `> 3`.

Using `unsigned` won't help here, it will just help moving the time until an overflow happens. `UINT_MAX` is approx twice as large as `INT_MAX`, so you will overflow it when adding the first three numbers, because `INT_MAX - 3 + INT_MAX - 6` will reach approx `UINT_MAX - 9`. Now adding `INT_MAX - 9` will definitely overflow `UINT_MAX - 9` because `INT_MAX - 9` is definitely `> 9`.

Instead, use `uint64_t`. Adding up *all* numbers from `1` to `2^31-1` (i.e `n*(n+1)/2`) will not be more than `2^63`, so you will definitely be on the safe side with `64` bits.

Comment: There is no signed integer overflow in C. If a result would become too large/small, undefined behvaiour is invoked. Anything can happen and the compiler is free to do anything. Unsigned would help in terms that it is defined to wrap, so it has a defined behaviour. Whether this is the intended result is another question.

Answer (score 0):

The result was too large to be fit into the `int` type, you should use `unsigned` type since there is no possible negative result, also change the format specifier to `%u` for `printf`:

```
unsigned int getsums(int v) {
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(;i<v; i++){
        if (i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0 ){
            sum +=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    int upperlimit = 0;
    unsigned int sums = 0;

    printf("Intervalo de 0 a (escreva um numero)\n");
    printf(">>");

    scanf("%d", &upperlimit);
    sums = getsums(upperlimit);

    printf("somas dos multiplos de 3 e 5 no intervalo [0;%d] e: %u\n", upperlimit, sums);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `unsigned` enough to hold the sum? Holding the sum of all values takes `n*(n+1)/2` which requires for 31 bits already around `60` bits. Now taking only every third takes more than `56` bits. There's no way all this fits into `32` bits. Am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: It adds up the numbers that are mutiple of 3 or 5.